# If $f(X), g(X) \in \mathbb{Q} [X]$ and $f(X) = g(X) h(X)$ , is $h(X)\in\mathbb{Q} [X]$?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

If $f(X), g(X) \in \mathbb{Q} [X]$ and $f(X) = g(X) h(X)$ , is $h(X)\in\mathbb{Q} [X]$ ?

Probably this is really really basic, but just in case I am missing something...

I think that in general $h$ may not be a polynomial, but if it is then is has to be a rational one. Is  that right? Any ideas how to prove it?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a Euclidean Ring, so has a "division algorithm" and unique factorization into irreducibles.  As a result, $h(x)$ will be a polynomial, so $h(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: $h(x)$ will be always a polynomial? Even if $\operatorname{gr}(f) < \operatorname{gr}(g)$ ?

Comment: If you don't know what $h$ is, how can you even define $g(X)h(X)$?
The notation and lack of quantification over $X$ suggests that $h$ is a polynomial, in fact I probably should even write "$h(X)$ is a polynomial". And you need to know where $h(X)$ is in. If this isn't explicit the problem statement, then I'd assume $h(X)$ is in $\mathbb R[X]$. I'd try to prove by induction on the degree of $h(X)$, if it were me.

Comment: In principle, it is only a function. I think it may have terms like $3 \frac{1}{X^2}$ that could allow the equation be satisfied. By the way, there is no problem statement because it is just a question that I am making to myself in order to test if my understanding about polynomials is consistent.

Comment: If $h$ can be a function, then you shouldn't write $h(X)$ or $\mathbb Q[X]$, but rather talk about polynomial functions. Consider $x\mapsto x, x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto \frac 1 x$ as $f, g$ and $h$, respectively.
If $h$, too, is a polynomial function, then its coefficients are rational, correct.

Answer (score 1):

$f(X) = g(X) h(X)$ gives a system of linear equations for the coefficients of $h$. If this system has a solution, than it has to remain in $\mathbb Q$ because it can be found by Gaussian elimination.